# How to show seo friendly url in mvc core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working on a mvc core 3.1 application. Seo requirements are to show product name with main site instead of complete url.

My original url is

[www.abc.com/Fashion/ProductDetail?productId=5088&productName=AliviaBlack&brandId=3](http://www.abc.com/Fashion/ProductDetail?productId=5088&productName=AliviaBlack&brandId=3)

Requirement are

```
www.abc.com/alivia-black
```

I have tried following by using attribute routing

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
           name: "SpecificRoute",
           pattern: "/{productName}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Fashion", action = "ProductDetail", id= "{productId}" });
```

In view page

```
 <a asp-route-productId="@product.ProductId"
                       asp-route-productName="@Common.FilterURL(product.ProductName)"
                       asp-route-brandId="@product.FashionBrand.FashionBrandId" asp-route="SpecificRoute">
```

Result is

```
www.abc.com/alivia-black?productId=5223&brandId=4
```

How to remove question mark and parameters after it.

Comment: I don't recommend using `<a asp-route-...` at all because it's so inflexible. Instead use your own custom URL-generation method. And you should still include the numeric `productId` value (as a route-parameter, not a query-string parameter) - otherwise links will break when products are renamed.

Comment: You should read this first: https://www.w3.org/2011/gld/wiki/223_Best_Practices_URI_Construction

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC or ASP.NET Core? You've tagged your question with both which is wrong.

Comment: @Dai thanks for the comment. Is it possible to hide productId and brandId in get request or i have to change it to post request by ajax ?

Comment: I don't think you read the link I posted. You **need** to include `productId` in your URIs (but it doesn't need to be a query-parameter). If you don't then you'll run into endless problems with broken-links. Also, I suspect you are unfamiliar with how HTTP works because you seem to misunderstand exactly how a POST request works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, URIs need to be resilient. You say your current requirement is to have URIs like this:

```
www.abc.com/alivia-black
```

i.e.:

```
{host}/{productName}
```

That's a **very bad** URI template because:

- It does not *uniquely* identify the product (as you could have multiple products with the same name).
- It will break existing links from external websites if you ever rename a product or replace a product with the same name. And this happens *a lot* in any product database.
- Because you're putting the `{productName}` in the "root" of your URI structure it means it's much harder to handle *anything else* besides viewing products (e.g. how would you have a `/contact-us` page? What if you had a product that was named `contact-us`?)

I stress that is is very important to include an immutable key to the entity being requested (in this case, your `productId` value) in the URI and use that as a primary-reference, so the `productName` can be ignored when handling an incoming HTTP request. This is how StackOverflow's and Amazon's URIs work (you can trim off the text after a StackOverflow's question-id and it will still work: e.g.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748993/how-to-show-seo-friendly-url-in-mvc-core-3-1

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69748993
```

[I strongly recommend you read this article on the W3.org's website all about designing good URIs](https://www.w3.org/2011/gld/wiki/223_Best_Practices_URI_Construction), as well as [other guidance from that group's homepage](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/).

---

I suggest you use a much better URI template, such as this one:

```
{host}/products/{productId}/{productName}
```

Which will give you a URI like this:

```
abc.com/products/5088/alivablack
```

Handling such a link in ASP.NET MVC (and ASP.NET Core) is trivial, just set the route-template on your controller action:

```
[Route( "/products/{productId:int}/{productName?}" )]
public async Task<IActionResult> ShowProduct( Int32 productId, String? productName = null )
{
    // Use `productId` to lookup the product.
    // Disregard `productName` unless you want to use it as a fallback to search your database if `productId` doesn't work.
}
```

As for *generating* URIs, as I recommend *against* using TagHelpers (e.g. `<a asp-route-`) because they don't give you sufficient control over how the URI is rendered, instead you can define a `UrlHelper` extension method (ensure you `@import` the namespace into your `.cshtml` pages (or add it to `ViewStart`):

```
public static class MyUrls
{
    public static String ShowProduct( this IUrlHelper u, Int32 productId, String productName )
    {
        const String ACTION_NAME = nameof(ProductsController.ShowProduct);
        const String CONTROLLER_NAME = "Products"; // Unfortunately we can't use `nameof` here due to the "Controller" suffix in the type-name.

        String url = u.Action( action: ACTION_NAME, controller: CONTROLLER_NAME, values: new { productId = productId, productName = productName } );
        return url;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
<a href="@Urls.ShowProduct( 5088, "aliviablack" )">View AliviaBlack</a>
```

You can also make `ShowProduct` accept one of your `Product` objects directly and then pass the values on to the other overload (defined above) which accepts scalars:

```
    public static String ShowProduct( this IUrlHelper u, Product product )
    {
        String url = ShowProduct( u, productId: product.ProductId, productName: product.ProductName );
        return url;
    }
```

Then you can use it like so (assuming `product` is in-scope):

```
<a href="@Urls.ShowProduct( product )">@product.ProductName</a>
```